# Is interacting with Web3 private?

Tags: metamask, dapps, privacy, browsers

If you're interacting with a dApp, e.g. connecting to a Web3-enabled site via MetaMask, would this interaction be private or is there a way for service providers to record your wallet address and any other details?

Comment: it is not private by default, if you aren't using secure HTTP everyone can see the packets and figure out what are you doing

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply connecting with a dapp, I don't think that they can track you from the blockchain. However if you sign a message to access their features, of course, they can tell.